# Handle url or image file data in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

my schema look like

```
var GameData = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    game_template: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'GameTemplate',
        index: true
    },
    data:{
         type: Schema.Types.Mixed 
    }]
```

now i handle images or url array of images 
but my data type is mixed type

```
if image came means store s3buckut and save db
or if url came means i saved directly
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Need more data as well, can you please add data for both the cases?